# Assigning an android property to an XML file with slight modifications

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, markup

This might be something basic, but I was unable to find the solution anywhere. So, suppose I had an `.xml` file called `properties.xml` in the drawable folder.
Say it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/GreenGray">

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

If I have multiple buttons in my `activity_main.xml`, and I want them all to have their background set to `properties.xml`, is there a way to change ONLY the background colors of the buttons so that they're all different from each other without making a whole new xml file for every button?

Kind of like how with classes with css, you can set an object to a class and change only specific properties of that class?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//get the button by id which you want do modify 
Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);

//get drawable from button
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) myBtn.getDrawable();

//set color
drawable.setColor(color)
```